# Identifying font embedding mechanism

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

Found this snippet on a site that is very well designed (http://www.distinctlydeutschland.com/):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'TrajanProBold';
    src: url('trajanpro-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('trajanpro-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('trajanpro-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('trajanpro-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('trajanpro-bold-webfont.svg#TrajanProBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

I currently use Google Fonts, and have used CUFON - this seems like a better alternative, as it offers more font selection (as I can probably upload my own font files it appears) and it also let's users drag-select the text, unlike CUFON.

Problem is I have no idea what this syntax means, or how the files (.woff, .eot etc.) are created, what they all do etc. If I just have .ttf will it work? Or is this generated by some web font service provider?

Comment: I started by downloading all the font files by directly inputting the URLs from the site.. I'll plug away on my own for now and see what I can dig out!

Comment: You host your own font files, reference the url within @font-face and can use them from within the stylesheet thereafter. There are hitches, though - http://symphony-of-dot-net.blogspot.com/2010/03/making-css-custom-font-works-with-ie.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@font-face is a way to define fonts for use within CSS. From that base you would use the following to set the font on an element with a class of `classname`:

```
.className {
    font-family:TrajanProBold;
}
```

Certain font formats only work on certain browsers, which is why there are multiple fallbacks.

There is a table of which formats work in which browsers here: http://www.stunningcss3.com/resources/fontface-file-types-browser-support.html

More information about @font-face: http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. That answers a lot of mysteries for me.